# Assign to a value its column name

Tags: r, dplyr

i'm working with dplyr, and i have a tibble like this:

```
df<- data_frame(one= c(1, NA, 1),
       two= c(NA,NA,1),
       three= c(1, 1,1)
       )
----------------------------
# A tibble: 3 x 3
      one   two  three
     <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
 1     1    NA     1
 2    NA    NA     1
 3     1     1     1
----------------------------
```

i need to obtain something like this:

```
----------------------------
# A tibble: 3 x 3
      one    two    three
     <dbl>  <dbl>   <dbl>
 1    one    NA     three
 2    NA     NA     three
 3    one    two    three
----------------------------
```

So i can use ifelse function with mutate for each column:

```
df %>%
      one= ifelse(!is.na(one),'one', NA ),
      two= ifelse(!is.na(two),'two', NA ),
      three= ifelse(!is.na(three),'three', NA ),
```

But in my real df i have many columns, then this wat is very inefficient.
i need something more elegant, using mutate_at and the column name but it's seem very hard.
I tried to do that in many ways but everytime i get an error.
Any advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there is only 1's and NAs in the dataset, multiply the `col(df)` with the dataset, `unlist` and based on the index, just replace it with `names` of the dataset and assign it back to the original data

```
df[] <- names(df)[unlist(col(df)*df)]
df
# A tibble: 3 x 3
#    one   two three
#  <chr> <chr> <chr>
#1   one  <NA> three
#2  <NA>  <NA> three
#3   one   two three
```

---

Or with `tidyverse`, we can do this for each column (`map2_df` from `purrr`)

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>%
     map2_df(names(.), ~replace(., !is.na(.), .y))
# A tibble: 3 x 3
#    one   two three
#  <chr> <chr> <chr>
#1   one  <NA> three
#2  <NA>  <NA> three
#3   one   two three
```

Comment: Thank you! it's perfect. In the dplyr mode can you explicit the function arguments you used? (.y= , .f=, ...)

Comment: @andriatz The `map2_df` takes two arguments `.x`, `.y`  Here the `.y` is one I specified first as `names(.)` i.e. names of the dataset